# can multiple csv's can be read using external table in oracle without specifying list of file names?

Tags: oracle, plsql, external-tables

I have 150 odd csv files but there file name may vary.
so i want to know whether in external table concept can we use *.csv where we provide file name list.

LOCATION (*.csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/external-table-enhancements-12cr1#oracle-loader-access-driver-enhancements), you can do it from 12c Release 1 (not tested):

> A number of minor usability improvements have been made to the
>   ORACLE_LOADER access driver to make external table creation simpler.
>   The LOCATION clause now accepts wildcards. An "*" matches multiple
>   characters, while a "?" matches a single character.
>
> ```
> LOCATION ('emp_ext*.dmp')
>
> LOCATION ('emp_ext?.dmp')
> ```

Answer (score -1):

From the docs:

The LOCATION clause lets you specify one or more external data sources. Usually the location_specifier is a file, but it need not be. Oracle Database does not interpret this clause. It is up to the access driver to interpret this information in the context of the external data.

So what happened when you tested it for yourself?